# File.listFiles() method returns inconsistant length

Tags: android

I wrote an application to display a flat list of android's entire file system. The flat list of the entire file system is constructed via a recursive method (below).

Now here's the issue: total number of paths obtained each time sometimes differs even though the code is not changed (e.g. results varies around +- 100 paths). Note that this issue only arise when *mLevelLimit* is set to > 0 (i.e. when recursion is performed).

```
private int mLevelLimit = 3; // the depth of the path to display
private int mLevelCount = 0;

private FileFilter mDirectoriesFilter = new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory();
    }
};

/**
 * Get entire system folder list.
 * 
 * @param parentDirectory
 *            the root directory
 */
private List<File> getFoldersList(File parentDirectory) {
    ArrayList<File> folderList = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = parentDirectory.listFiles(mDirectoriesFilter);

    if (files != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            folderList.add(file);

            if (mLevelCount < mLevelLimit) {
                mLevelCount++;
                folderList.addAll(getFoldersList(file));
                mLevelCount--;
            }
        }
    }

    return folderList;
}
```

I have tried searching if there are any reported known issues with File.listFiles() API but couldn't find any results. So I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my recursive method instead. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root cause of the returned length/size inconsistencies from File.listFiles() method. The variation is caused by the system folders being modified at run-time (e.g. one moment I may have /proc/31683 folder, but another moment this folder has been removed by the system). In other words, my codes original are working perfectly fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on [File.listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29),

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array
>   will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular,
>   guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

So your recursion probably takes different paths every time you run it. To achieve the desired effect you may want to sort the array you get from `listFiles()` prior to iteration.

Comment: It is not an issue about the order of the resulting list, but the size of the resulting list being different sometimes. I have posted the answer to my own question and only able to mark it as an answer tomorrow. Thanks :)